# How to call custom made wordpress menu in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I've made a custom menu (that is not default) in Appearance > Menus
How do I call it in php files?

I can only find tutorials how to call default menu or menu registered inside php with wp_nav_menu function, but how do I call custom menu made in wordpress's cms?

Comment: Checkout this tutorial: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add pages to the menu on the menu screen. Then, your theme will automatically show it on your website. Be sure to make it your Main menu at the bottom of the menu page under Menu Settings.